# Why does Cloud Foundry's UAA /token_keys endpoint contain a 'cache-control: no-store' response header?

Tags: http-headers, jwt, cloud-foundry, cache-control, cloudfoundry-uaa

I was reading over `cache-control` request/response headers [here](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/glossary/cache-control.html).

Definition of `Cache-Control: No-Store`:

`The no-store directive means browsers aren’t allowed to cache a response and must pull it from the server each time it’s requested. This setting is usually used for sensitive data, such as personal banking details.`

Cloud Foundry UAA stores its public keys for JWT signature validation at `https://uaa.my-domain.com/token_keys` and it's `cache-control` response header contains `no-store`.

This makes no sense to me - they are public keys that do not require authorization to acquire. Additionally, there is an `ETag` response header that implies, according to the link referenced above, that a browser or client will be caching the response.

Comment: I would recommend filing an issue: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa